# "Invalid canvas size" while rendering PDF to PNG using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf.js

I'm having trouble making the PDF.js library render a PDF to a PNG file.

My steps are :

1. `mkdir pdf-test`
2. `npm init`
3. `npm install pdfjs-dist assert canvas`
4. Copy `pdf2png.js` from the [examples](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/node/pdf2png) page to the working folder
5. Copy a random PDF to this folder, set path to it in `pdf2png.js` on line 54
6. `node pdf2png.js`

I'm getting the following output:

```
# PDF document loaded.
(node:13760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid canvas size
    at NodeCanvasFactory_create [as create] (D:\tests\pdf-test\pdf2png.js:23:5)
    at D:\tests\pdf-test\pdf2png.js:70:21
```

Surprisingly, if I clone the entire PDF.js repository and follow the instructions to build it from source, the script work fine and I get a correctly rendered PNG file.

What am I missing when installing a prebuilt version from NPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an update.

The latest `pdfjs-dist` npm version is `v2.0.943` from `Oct 27, 2018`, while the latest GitHub release is `v2.1.266` from `Feb 16, 2019`.

This latest update has this changelog: [migrate to canvas 2.x api](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/10399) which also affected `pdf2png.js` file, as you can see here:

[image]

So if you used the latest `pdf2png.js` file from `pdf.js` GitHub repository, you had some kind of version mismatch between the `pdfjs-dist` npm package and the `pdf2png.js` file.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Updating to `2.1.226` actually solved the issue!